# What are the current best practices for validating email addresses in forms?

Tags: regex, validation, email

I know there are some complicated regular expressions that can help with this, but I'm wondering if this approach is even being used these days?

My particular question has to do with a "Get a Quote" form on a website I'm building. Sending a validation email to the user requiring a response might not be appropriate since no accounts are being set up. But are regular expressions the way to go? I'm just wondering what's being done about this these days.

Comment: Check it contains an @ sign. Send an email to them asking to confirm their quote request. If they click the link in the email, then you know you're not wasting your time, and the quote is actually going to be delivered

Comment: If you want to be sure of the email address, you need to send it some email. Otherwise, you might not even care (or perhaps test that there is some `@` followed by a `.`  in it).

Comment: Verification email is the only way that is both simple and reliable.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Checking for `.` will reject "valid" email addresses like "email@com". Checking for `@` is better than nothing, because it stops people from typing a username by mistake

Answer (score 1):

Using regexes for validating emails is quite useless.

They don't catch typos in email addresses. Use email verification form field for this.

They don't ensure that syntactically valid email address actually exists. If you want the email address to be able to send them some mails, then this is what you have to do, send the verification email with a link. If you don't want to send them emails, then, from your perspective, there's no difference between "foobar1234" and "12856723984562983456283456@example.com".

And besides, unless you go [full RFC](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) on this, there will be some pissed off users with "strange" emails which your regex rejected.